# HTTP Header Xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, http-headers

I am try to send token as a Header and is supposed to get back XML data back. It works perfectly on Postman. But in App, it is returning a HTML page With title `RESTRICTED PAGE, Status = 200 OK`.

Here is the Code

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result);
var response = await client.GetAsync("https:my.url");
string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Console.WriteLine(content);
```

Can anyone please tell me what am i doing wrong ? Are there any other Settings i need to give in Info.Plist ? I already gave `NSAllowArbitary = true`.

Comment: Are you sure the result is ok?

Comment: @BrunoCaceiro : You mean HTTP STATUS ??

Comment: the token, if it is valid. And if your url is correct

Comment: It's better to ask your sever side under which situation would returning a HTML page With title `RESTRICTED PAGE, Status = 200 OK`.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT: Sure thank you

Comment: @BrunoCaceiro : Yes both of them are valid i double checked them...Both of them are valid

Comment: Got it. Cleared all the cookies on the webview and again sent the token as header. Its working